# Redirect to a specified Url when a Controller method is accessed through a browser?

Tags: c#, rest, redirect

Is it possible to be redirected to *http://google.com* when *http://myapiservice.com/api/someaction?param=test* is accessed through a browser(Get method)?

Also an added note, it will never be accessed using `HTTP GET` as its real implementation would be `HTTP PUT`. I was just planning to create a method to handle `Get` requests. Any help would highly be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. Put this in your action:

```
return Redirect("http://www.google.com");
```